# Get variable from ng-repeat to javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to call a script that will open up a new page with some info about that "thing" I just clicked.

The problem is that data is dynamic and I loop through it with angular, this is the HTML part:

```
<div id="product">
    <div ng-repeat="producto in productos" id="{{ producto.id }}">    
        <div class="figuranta" id="{{ producto.id }}" >
            <figure class="floating" id="{{ producto.id }}" onclick="details({{ producto.id }});">
              <img  ng-src="{{ producto.image }}" alt="image" class="rcorners3" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
              <figcaption> {{ producto.name }} {{ producto.id }}</figcaption>

            </figure>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I pass that angularjs id to the "details" script? I already know about the ng-click,  I need to pass it to javascript though, unless ng-click can call a JS script in the header. Every **id="{{ producto.id }}"** shows up correctly but the one in the onclick event. Is it possible at all to achieve? Or, is it possible to call with ng-click a JS function that is placed locally in the header or it'll only call functions in the Main

Comment: If you can call onclick="details(...)", then for sure you can call details function from controller. $scope.details = function(id) { details(id )} and to call this one use ng-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TIL** that if you want to pass an angularJS variable to a local JS script to the header you need to do it like this:

```
    <div id="product">
    <div ng-repeat="producto in productos" id="{{ producto.id }}">    
        <div class="figuranta" id="{{ producto.id }}" >
            <figure class="floating" id="{{ producto.id }}" onclick="details(id);">
              <img  ng-src="{{ producto.image }}" alt="image" class="rcorners3" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
              <figcaption> {{ producto.name }} {{ producto.id }}</figcaption>

            </figure>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And not like in the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead of `onclick`:

```
ng-click="details(producto.id);"
```

And define `details` function on `scope` in controller.

```
$scope.details = function (productId) {
    // Code here
```

---

Also,

You don't need mustache for `ng-src`(or any other angular directive) in

```
 ng-src="{{ producto.image }}"
```

Use

```
 ng-src="producto.image"
```

Comment: @AndreiLorincz Then, you can call your function in JS header, from the controller. Like `$scope.details = function() {details(arguments)}`;